# Add exit confirmation dialog in brave browser

Tags: windows-10, browser, ubuntu-20.04, brave

Often I Accidently close **brave browser** and even though I have selected `continue were you left off` `On Startup` still I am struggling to find how to enable **exit confirmation setting** .

Is there is a way through which I can enable or add exit confirmation functionality on brave.

Answer (score 4):

#### Can I enable or add exit confirmation functionality on brave.

This is currently only possible on MacOS. There is an open issue to add this functionality to Windows/Linux:

> Several users have requested the option to confirm whether or not they want to close a window when multiple tabs are open in it. This functionality would be similar to what is already implemented in other browsers like Firefox and IE

Source: [Add "warning/confirmation" dialog when closing a window w/ multiple tabs · Issue #10430 · brave/brave-browser · GitHub](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/10430)

See Also: [Warning to close if multiple tabs open? - Browser Support / Desktop Support - Brave Community](https://community.brave.com/t/warning-to-close-if-multiple-tabs-open/167327/2)

Comment: I guess Brendan has a Mac, and he does not really care about other platforms.

This seems trivial to implement, and Brave developpers really should care more about such issues. (Not) losing work is so much more important than slowly picking cents in exchange for ad views.